# How to customize the grid layout in reactive pro wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins

I am using **[Reactive Pro](http://redq.io/portfolio/reactive-pro-advanced-wordpress-search-filtering-grid/)**  wordpress plugin in one of my wordpress site. This plugin provides several types of layout of grids for your post and products pages.

This plugin uses node and react to do changes in grid layouts. And the changes instructions given here : https://redq.gitbooks.io/reactive/content/grid_addons.html

I follow the instructions as these are provided but I am not able to change the grid layout.

Is anybody have knowledge about how to change grid layouts of this plugin?